# Magento 1.9 sort collection by one of the fields value

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting, cms-block

Whetever I do it still gives me the same results. 
Querying cms_block ids:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel( 'cms/block' )
        ->getCollection()
    // can't add addAttributeToSelect(whatever name here or esterisk because it is casing ..error)
        ->addFieldToFilter( 'is_active', 1 )
        ->addFieldToFilter( 'is_slide', 1 )
    ;
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->order('position ASC');
```

Tried various sort methods but ... no luck.
Any ideas how to get cms/block ids sorted by position ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 1.9.x CMS Static Blocks are saved in *cms_block* table which doesn't have any field called "position". So you cannot sort by "position".
Secondly the arguments for setOrder method is

> setOrder('field_name','sortdirection')

Hope this helps. Just presented a working code which filters the CMS Blocks by active status and order by name (title) in descending order.

```
$cmsBlockCollection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();
$cmsBlockCollection->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1);
$cmsBlockCollection->setOrder('title','DESC');
```

or you can also order the collection by this way

```
$cmsBlockCollection->getSelect()->order('title','DESC');
```

Comment: $collection = Mage::getModel( 'cms/block' )
   ->getCollection()
   //->addAttributeToSelect('position')
   ->addFieldToFilter( 'is_active', 1 )
   ->addFieldToFilter( 'is_slide', 1 )
  ;
  $collection->setOrder('position','DESC'); What's the difference ?

Comment: Regardless if ASC or DESC it gives me the same order Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 6 [3] => 7 [4] => 9 [5] => 10 [6] => 12 [7] => 13 [8] => 15 [9] => 16 [10] => 17 [11] => 22 [12] => 24 [13] => 26 [14] => 27 [15] => 28 [16] => 29 [17] => 32 [18] => 34 [19] => 36 [20] => 42 [21] => 47 )

Comment: There is a significant difference, CMS static block collection is a non-eav so its recommended to use addFieldToSelect or addFieldToFilter when you deal with non-eav collection, because it has only fields not attributes. Whereas EAV entities like <product>, <category>, <order>, <customer> data stored in EAV tables, which has attributes so its recommended to use addAttributeToFilter or addAttributeToSort methods when you deal with EAV collection.

Comment: However, with or without addAttribute, it just won't geive me back array in order I want. Assume that the best and the easiest way will be just sql query instead of d..b Magento collection  method?

Comment: its wierd , can you print your query  echo $cmsBlockCollection->getSelect()->__toString() and let me know what you got.

Comment: Ohhh I understand now. Thank you for precise explanation. Will now try to use this way.

Comment: Like a stubborn donkey i was doing it in completely wrong way. I was sure that sort should change order of the ID's .... wrong, getAllIds is sorting them back in ASC order whatever order is requested.At least I think it is like that

Comment: no problem, its a typical story in a developer's day some point of time. Hope you are able to sort your collection. Always print / log your collection SQL during development , which would be very useful for debugging. The following code works well to sort the CMS blocks by their title in descending order. You can substitute your fields to get it done. $cmsBlockCollection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();
$cmsBlockCollection->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1);
$cmsBlockCollection->getSelect()->order('title','DESC');

Comment: Thank you Haijerome, all sorted. I'm just rebuilding slide system ( Ultimo - which is in my opinion a little bit .... no good/overcomplicated :) )  now it's simple and very easy to use even for the people who know nothing about how to add image to the block. Thanx again

Comment: no problem Rob, you're most welcome. With this very active forum you can easily get help to customize your Magento Ultimo theme.